# laravel 9 database foreign key issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, migration

I try to add foreign keys to products and images. I added it a few days ago same way but today it returned this error "1005 Can't create table" "PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `example`.`images` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")"

This is images migration

```
Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->string('path');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And this is the products table migration

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('brand')->nullable();
        $table->string('model')->nullable();
        $table->string('type')->nullable();
        $table->string('power')->nullable();
        $table->string('maximum_heating_temperature')->nullable();
        $table->string('surface_material')->nullable();
        $table->enum('display', ['yes','no'])->default('no');
        $table->enum('temperature_regulation',['yes','no'])->default('no');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: Did you create the `images` migration before `products`?

Comment: Yes this was the reason, thanks